# How to resize column of a webbrowser in c# win form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using c# net 4.5. I have a tablelayout panel containing 2 columns each is of size 50%.Now these 2 columns contain 2 webbrowsers.Webbrowser contained in column may or may not have data while webbrowser in column 2 will always have data to show.Hence based on certain conditions i want the width of column 1 to be set to 0% and that of column to be 100% and so on..

I have written some codes to do so but their width does not resize accordingly.

```
if (x == "<p><br _mce_bogus=\"1\"></p>")
{
    this.webBrowserDir.Visible = false;
    this.webBrowserDesc.DocumentStream = new MemoryStream(qDescArray);
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanelWBrowsers.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 0));
        }
        else
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanelWBrowsers.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
        }
    }
    //
}
else
{
    this.webBrowserDir.Visible = true;
    this.webBrowserDir.DocumentStream = new MemoryStream(qDirArray);
    this.webBrowserDesc.DocumentStream = new MemoryStream(qDescArray);
}
```

Please advice with codes.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely it is pointless to *add* column styles.  Just modify the existing ones, this.tableLayoutPanelWBrowsers.ColumnStyles[0].Width = 0

Comment: Cool!...It works just like wanted it to...Thanks @Hans Passant. :)